# Get value stored at address

Tags: go, memory-address

I'm starting to learn GO and would like for someone to help me understand something. How can I read the value at address that is returned by `syscall.GetcomputerName`? I understand that that call will store the address in variable `y`. Thank you

```
package main

import "fmt"

import "syscall"
import "os"

func main() {
    x, err := os.Hostname()
    y := syscall.GetComputerName
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(y)

}
```

Comment: Since that's a function, it will be the address of the function. But that's really not very useful. Why don't you try calling the function?

Comment: as I said I'm just starting to learn Go, not too sure how to go about this in this instance

Comment: You add `()`, but it looks like it takes two arguments, so you'd have to provide the arguments too.

Comment: ok makes sense, I just checked the definition but not sure how to implement or if Im actually using it properly: func GetComputerName(buf *uint16, n *uint32) (err error) {}

Comment: @user7421969 sorry, what are you trying to achieve? I assume you need to get the computer name information of you machine, is that correct?

Comment: @xpare2 yes I'm trying to see how different packages react. I already know how to get the os package to work and as you can see I'm using  os.Hostname() and it returns the correct value

Comment: @user7421969 ok, so I think better to learn it using any other package which is easier. `syscall`-related function has very limited documentation compared to other package

Comment: There's no documentation there because the Go function is merely a very thin wrapper over the [corresponding Win32 function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcomputernamew), which documentation you should read if you want to know how to call it. Better yet, avoid it entirely and use the higher level `os` calls, which don't require you to do `unsafe` stuff. At least until you have more experience with Go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`syscall.GetComputerName` is the address of the function. To execute the `syscall.GetComputerName` function use the function call operator `()`. For example, on Windows,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unicode/utf16"
)

func ComputerName() (name string, err error) {
    var n uint32 = syscall.MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1
    b := make([]uint16, n)
    e := syscall.GetComputerName(&b[0], &n)
    if e != nil {
        return "", e
    }
    return string(utf16.Decode(b[0:n])), nil
}

func main() {
    name, err := ComputerName()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("ComputerName:", name)
}
```

Output:

```
ComputerName: PETER
```

---

[Microsoft: GetComputerNameW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcomputernamew)

Comment: Thank you Peter! Your example explains it very well